# Pandas says 7 in df["C"] but actually asking for the indices of 7 returns empy list - why?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a couple of thousand lines. One column is called `C` and it is of interest to know whether the number 7 occurs in the column.

I tried: `print(7 in df["C"])` and it returned `True`, however `print(df.index[df["C"] == 7].tolist())` returns `[]`.

What is going on here? What aspect of `in` am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `in` check value of indices, it is [gotcha](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d'],
    'C': list(range(10, 19))
})
print (df)
   A   C
0  a  10
1  a  11
2  a  12
3  a  13
4  b  14
5  b  15
6  b  16
7  c  17
8  d  18

print(7 in df["C"])
True

print(10 in df["C"])
False
```

And in column `C` is no value `7`, so returned empty list:

```
print(df.index[df["C"] == 7].tolist())
```

Comment: Ugh. This is embarrasing. Thank you.