# Difference between using 'in' for lists and Pandas series

Tags: python, list, pandas

I am wondering what causes the different behaviour between lists and pandas series when using 'in'. Here is an Example:

```
'a' in ['a' ,'b','c','d']
#returns True
'a' in pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])
#returns False
```

I know that I can use the .isin() function to get the required behaviour:

```
pd.Series(['a','b','c','d']).isin(['a'])
#returns Boolean array
```

forcing the series back to a list leads to the required behaviour

```
'a' in list(pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])
#returns True
```

what is it about pandas data structures that doesn't allow 'in' to work as it does with lists?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48558545/2901002)

Comment: `'a' in pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])` check membership of indices

Comment: `2 in pd.Series(['a','b','c','d'])` return `True`

Comment: `in` tests for indices: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters that is exactly what I was looking for